# Intellij Idea Run/Debug Configurations

Tags: intellij-idea

In Idea (I am using 12.0), I have the option of deploying either a war file, or an exploded war file.

I have a Spring MVC/Maven project that I am developing (not packaging for production yet).  Can someone educate me on which one I should choose, and why?  I am interested in the fastest and most convenient at this point, since I am just developing.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `exploded war` for the [faster updates](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/updating-a-running-java-ee-application.html) (without redeployment) when developing.

`war` should be used when you want to prepare your app for deployment on the production server.

Comment: Absolutely correct. Using the exploded war you can easily hot swap code changes you've made (check the IDE settings -> Debugger -> Hotswap) and use jRebel for even faster turn-around times. And don't forget the "build on make" checkbox on your exploded war artifact.